# error: Could not find document for file ... under target project workspace in process upgrade from Framework to .Net6

Tags: .net, frameworks, migration, migrate

When I try to upgrade my project from Framework to .Net6 by migration tools, I get an error messages as

> error: Could not find document for file "Some File Path" under target project workspace

I can`t find an answer, and want a right solution, that will help me.
I've deleted hidden folders and excluded folders and files and migration successfully done.

I can`t find answer on any other resources.

Comment: I have the same issue on upgrading to .NET 6 for specflow (.feature.cs) files

Answer (score 0):

The files that produce the error are not included in the project workspace. Therefore they are not used to build your project.

In my case deleting the files before I upgraded to .NET 6 helped.
That way, the upgrade assistant does not find any documents in the project folder, that are not in your project workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted hidden folders in project folder, hidden excluded folders and files in project tree and migration successfull do.